# Anchor 1x2 wood on cabinet side wall

Tags: cabinets, anchor, shelf

Can anyone recommend a good method of anchoring a 1x2 9" wood strip on the side of the cabinet wall?  The strip will be used as a shelving bracket. I don't expect there to be a lot of weight but I'd like it to be pretty secure for holding the shelf.

It seems like screws would be a bad idea since the wall is only 3/4" thick. Perhaps I could drill a hole and use nut, bolt, lock washer? Would this work, and can you suggest a screw size and length? I've thought about adhesive such as Loctite, but I'm not found of the permanancy of that idea. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What material is the cabinet side? Plywood? Particle board? Typical solution here is to screw from the interior of the cabinet to the wood. If you're really scared, use a nut/bolt combo.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not aware of any Loctite formulas that are designed for use in wood. Nor would any sort of thread locker be necessary. They're designed to prevent screws from backing out when under severe vibration. Unless you're putting a mighty, thumpin' sub-woofer on this shelf, you're not going to have that much vibration going on.

Comment: Loctite has expanded their product line and now have products similar to Gorilla and Titebond.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding exposed supporting bracket for the shelves, and fairly large one at that, 1x2s, screws are the appropriate way to attach and remain removable.  Pre drill the holes and contersink for the screw heads in the wood strips.  Select screw length to just go deep enough in the side without punching through.

Screws similiar in size to drywall screws- 1-1/4 or 1-1/2" long, Measure the thickness of the wood strip and the cabinet wall to determine the screw lengh. Screws long enough to get good penetration in the cabinet wall without punching through the inside.

Comment: Right, but I'd take Aloysius Defenestrate's advice and go inside-out. 1-1/4" screws were designed for this exact purpose. Be aware that a screw doesn't need to actually punch through to cause a bulge. Accurately pre-drill the cabinet panel by putting tape on the bit as a depth gauge to reduce that chance.